# Проблема с описанием типов для существующего пакета

Tags: typescript

## Проблема с описанием типов для существующего пакета

Хочу потренироваться в написании типов для существующего пакета JS

#### Для примера взял пакет debug без типов

репозитарий с необходимыми файлами:
https://github.com/Ulibka68/pk2

Сам код состоит из трех строк:

```
import  createDebug from 'debug';
export const debug = createDebug('node-kraken-ws')
debug('start');
```

Дополнительно в директории types создал поддиректорию debug в которую положил файл index.d.ts:

```
declare module 'debug' {
    export function createDebug(a:string) : unknown;
}
```

В tsconfig добавил:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
```

Такой код дает ошибку:

```
cli.ts:1:22 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("debug")' has no call signatures.
```

Получается что tsc почему то не подхватывает описания типов, хотя я вроде бы все правильно сделал.
Секцию "types" - которая ограничивает перечень импортируемых типов я убрал

проблема конечно решается импортом типов командой:

```
npm i -D @types/debug
```

Но Я хочу попробовать написать определения типов самостоятельно.
Почему у меня это не получается ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас у вас объявлено, что в модуле `debug` есть функция `createDebug`. А на самом деле вам нужно объявить, что сам модуль и является этой функцией. Вот так:

```
declare module 'debug' {
    export default function createDebug(namespace: string): unknown;
}
```

после чего вы получите ошибку от компилятора на строчке `debug('start')`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Действительно все заработало.
Вы добавили волшебное слово default.
Я себе всю голову сломал - наверно часа два рылся в интернете но так и не понял в чем проблема :)